# tvOS Top Shelf doesn't show local images on real devices

Tags: ios, objective-c, traits, tvos, topshelf

This problem seems to have no sense and it is driving me crazy.
I have the top-shelf which works correctly on simulator showing images from the web and from local files.
However, when I try it on a real device it only shows the images from the web.

```
// Some irrelevant code to manipulate the image
// .....

NSString *filename = @"image-name";
NSArray<NSString *> *paths = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSCachesDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES);
NSString *filepath = [paths.firstObject stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];
                
[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage, 0.8) writeToFile:filepath atomically:NO]; // <- tried also with YES
                
NSURL *finalURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];

// Tried to see if the image is stored and is correct and it is on both, simulator and device.
// Simulator and device both run iOS 13.4.1.
                
if (@available(tvOS 11.0, *)) {
    // I set it for both traits although is not needed.
    [item setImageURL:finalURL forTraits:TVContentItemImageTraitScreenScale1x];
    [item setImageURL:finalURL forTraits:TVContentItemImageTraitScreenScale2x];
} else {
    item.imageURL = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:filepath];
}
```

As I said above, this shows the image perfectly on the simulator but not on the device.

As far as I remember, this used to work some time ago.

Does anyone have insights?

Thanks.

Comment: how do you manage to place your image into NSCachesDirectory? It should be NSDocumentDirectory unless your file is part of your Assets or you explicitly placed it in NSCachesDirectory.

Comment: I explicitly put it in the Cache directory as per code I posted above `[UIImageJPEGRepresentation(newImage, 0.8) writeToFile:filepath atomically:NO];`
On tvOS you cannot store anything in the document directory.